# Failed to determine the https port for redirect in AWS ECS

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

Getting this error in an AWS ECS service "Failed to determine the https port for redirect"
Haven't been able to find root cause.

To future troubleshoot I created a new .NET Core Web API project using VS 2022, targeting .NET 6, and it produced the following launchSettings.json

**Notice there are 2 different SSL ports 44301 and 7005**

Can this cause the breaking change described in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/middleware-ambiguous-https-ports-exception

And more importantly, do the ports need to be the same for sslPort and applicationUrl settings?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2280",
      "sslPort": 44301
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7005;http://localhost:5005",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This honestly doesn't appear to be related to ECS or AWS at all. It just looks like a .NET configuration issue that should be independent of where the app is running. What if you run the same docker image locally, do you get the same error?

Comment: @MarkB I don't think this is AWS ECS issue either. I added that provide more context of the application. For now we resolved the issue by disabling HttpsRedirect in app builder since this is an internal only microservice. I guess my main question is why VS is producing ambiguous https ports in launchSettings.json